# MATLAB - How to prevent tabulate function returning frequencies of variables that are not present in the vector?

Tags: matlab, crosstab, tabulate

I have the vector v1, with 26 elements, either being 'Live' or 'Non-live'.
When I use tabulate(v1), it returns

```
tabulate(v1)
       Value    Count   Percent
        cat1        0      0.00%
        cat2        0      0.00%
        Live        5     19.23%
    Non-live       21     80.77%
```

This affects crosstab also. How to prevent tabulate and crosstab functions taking non-existing variables in the vector in to account?

Answer (score 0):

From the example [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tabulate.html#mw_20a76027-6b09-4d8b-aa55-7c4175dd13d0) it suggests you might get results in tabulate that aren't in your data if your variable isn't categorical. Try converting it to categorical and running `tabulate` again.

```matlab
categorical_v1 = categorical(v1);
tabulate(categorical_v1)
```

It looks like `v1` could already be categorical, but perhaps it was not set up correctly, so `cat1` and `cat2` are remnants of this. "Recategorising" the data should remove these extra categories.

Comment: v1 is already categorical. Running categorical function on it again and running tabulate and crosstab still gives the same output.

Comment: Can you check the categories of the data by `categories(v1)`? If that returns only `Live` and `Non-live` that suggests it must be a `tabulate` issue.

Comment: categories(v1) also returns cat1 and cat2

Comment: But `unique(v1)` doesn't contain cat1 and cat2? How about `categories(categorical(v1))`? Or `categories(categorical(v1, {'Live','Non-live'}))`?